How to maintain compiled Linux drivers through updates
I built a new PC using the new AMD 870 chipset. This came with a Realtek 5gb network adapter that doesn't seem to be supported out of the box with Debian or NixOS distros. I was able to download the driver from here. I then booted from a thumb drive on another PC and used this answer to download all the packages I needed like build-essentials and the kernel headers to compile and install the driver. Once I had a network connection I saw I had a lot of updates so I ran an apt-get update. This apparently bumped by kernel version from 6.1.0.25 to 6.1.0.26 and removed that network driver leaving me without internet again. The update did not download new kernel headers. I could no longer use my live image to download the new headers and dependencies since it was out of date. Instead of making an new live image I downloaded what I needed manually on another computer, transferred the files, and recompiled the driver again.
Is there an easier way to keep my network card alive through patches? Do I need to go buy an ethernet dongle and just expect to repeat this every time I patch my system?

Yes, there's an easier way: https://wiki.debian.org/KernelDKMS

Tes, @ChanganAuto; I use DKMS to automatically add Realtek drivers after updates. You might expand your comment to an answer.
